# Android: ListFragment always show init list on background

Tags: android, list, selection

I am trying to implement three ListFragments in the main activity.  The third list is a sub-list of the second one while the second one is a sub-list of the first one.  I started with the FragmentLayout example from the API demo.  After I added those three ListFragments, I could see that whenever I made a selection, I always see the screen is first showing the list with the first selections (all ListFragments) and then the new ListFragment is drawn on top of it.  Also, those first selections (NFL, NFC West, 49ers) are always highlighted even a different entry is selected.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

From the code below, I always see this in the background:

NFL    NFC West    49ers
MLB    NFC East    Seahawks
       AFC West    Rams
                   Cardinals

Here is the code:

```
public class FragmentLayout2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }


    /**
     * This is a secondary activity, to show what the user has selected
     * when the screen is not large enough to show it all in one activity.
     */

    public static class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
                    == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                // If the screen is now in landscape mode, we can show the
                // dialog in-line with the list so we don't need this activity.
                finish();
                return;
            }
/*
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
                DetailsFragment details = new DetailsFragment();
                details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, details).commit();
            }
            */
        }
    }


    /**
     * This is the "top-level" fragment, showing a list of items that the
     * user can pick.  Upon picking an item, it takes care of displaying the
     * data to the user as appropriate based on the current UI layout.
     */

    public static class TitlesFragment0 extends ListFragment {
        boolean mDualPane0;
        int mCurCheckPosition0 = 0;
        int mShownCheckPosition0 = -1;
        TitlesFragment1 tf1 = null;

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // Populate list with our static array of titles.
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, Shakespeare.TITLES0));

            // Check to see if we have a frame in which to embed the details
            // fragment directly in the containing UI.
            View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.titles1);
            mDualPane0 = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                // Restore last state for checked position.
                mCurCheckPosition0 = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice0", 0);
                mShownCheckPosition0 = savedInstanceState.getInt("shownChoice0", -1);
            }

            if (mDualPane0) {
                // In dual-pane mode, the list view highlights the selected item.
                getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                // Make sure our UI is in the correct state.
                showDetails(mCurCheckPosition0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt("curChoice0", mCurCheckPosition0);
            outState.putInt("shownChoice0", mShownCheckPosition0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            showDetails(position);
        }

        /**
         * Helper function to show the details of a selected item, either by
         * displaying a fragment in-place in the current UI, or starting a
         * whole new activity in which it is displayed.
         */
        void showDetails(int index) {
            mCurCheckPosition0 = index;

            if (mDualPane0) {
                // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
                // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
                getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

                if (mShownCheckPosition0 != mCurCheckPosition0) {
                    // If we are not currently showing a fragment for the new
                    // position, we need to create and install a new one.
                    //TitlesFragment1 df = TitlesFragment1.newInstance(index);
                    if (tf1==null)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FragmentTransaction ft2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft2.remove(tf1);
                        ft2.commit();
                    }
                    tf1 = TitlesFragment1.newInstance(index);
                    // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
                    // with this one inside the frame.
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.titles1, tf1);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    ft.commit();
                    mShownCheckPosition0 = index;
                }

            } else {
                // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
                // the dialog fragment with selected text.
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("index0", index);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }


    public static class TitlesFragment1 extends ListFragment {
        boolean mDualPane1;
        int mCurCheckPosition1 = 0;
        int mShownCheckPosition1 = -1;
        TitlesFragment2 tf2 = null;

        public static TitlesFragment1 newInstance(int index) {
            TitlesFragment1 f = new TitlesFragment1();

            // Supply index input as an argument.
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("index0", index);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }


        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            int upIndex = 0;
            if (getArguments() != null)
                upIndex = getArguments().getInt("index0", 0);

            // Populate list with our static array of titles.
            if (upIndex==0)
                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, Shakespeare.TITLES00));
            else
                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, Shakespeare.TITLES01));

            // Check to see if we have a frame in which to embed the details
            // fragment directly in the containing UI.
            View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.titles2);
            mDualPane1 = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                // Restore last state for checked position.
                mCurCheckPosition1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice1", 0);
                mShownCheckPosition1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("shownChoice1", -1);
            }

            if (mDualPane1) {
                // In dual-pane mode, the list view highlights the selected item.
                getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                // Make sure our UI is in the correct state.
                showDetails(mCurCheckPosition1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt("curChoice1", mCurCheckPosition1);
            outState.putInt("shownChoice1", mShownCheckPosition1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            showDetails(position);
        }

        /**
         * Helper function to show the details of a selected item, either by
         * displaying a fragment in-place in the current UI, or starting a
         * whole new activity in which it is displayed.
         */
        void showDetails(int index) {
            mCurCheckPosition1 = index;

            int upIndex = 0;
            if (getArguments() != null)
                upIndex = getArguments().getInt("index0", 0);

            if (mDualPane1) {
                // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
                // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
                getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

                if (mShownCheckPosition1 != mCurCheckPosition1) {
                    // If we are not currently showing a fragment for the new
                    // position, we need to create and install a new one.
                    //TitlesFragment2 df = TitlesFragment2.newInstance(upIndex, index);
                    if (tf2==null)
                    {

                    }                   
                    else
                    {
                        FragmentTransaction ft2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft2.remove(tf2);
                        ft2.commit();

                    }
                    tf2 = TitlesFragment2.newInstance(upIndex, index);
                    // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
                    // with this one inside the frame.
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.titles2, tf2);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    ft.commit();

                    mShownCheckPosition1 = index;
                }

            } else {
                // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
                // the dialog fragment with selected text.
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("index0", upIndex);
                intent.putExtra("index1", index);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class TitlesFragment2 extends ListFragment {
        boolean mDualPane2;
        int mCurCheckPosition2 = 0;
        int mShownCheckPosition2 = -1;

        public static TitlesFragment2 newInstance(int upIndex, int index) {
            TitlesFragment2 f = new TitlesFragment2();

            // Supply index input as an argument.
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("index0", upIndex);
            args.putInt("index1", index);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }


        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            int upIndex0 = 0;
            int upIndex1 = 0;
            if (getArguments() != null)
            {
                upIndex0 = getArguments().getInt("index0", 0);
                upIndex1 = getArguments().getInt("index1", 0);
            }

            if (upIndex0 == 0)
            {
                if (upIndex1 == 0)
                    // Populate list with our static array of titles.
                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, Shakespeare.TITLES000));
                else if (upIndex1 == 1)
                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, Shakespeare.TITLES001));
                else
                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, Shakespeare.TITLES002));
            }
            else
            {
                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, Shakespeare.TITLES010));
            }
            // Check to see if we have a frame in which to embed the details
            // fragment directly in the containing UI.
            View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.titles2);
            mDualPane2 = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                // Restore last state for checked position.
                mCurCheckPosition2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice2", 0);
                mShownCheckPosition2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("shownChoice2", -1);
            }

            if (mDualPane2) {
                // In dual-pane mode, the list view highlights the selected item.
                getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                // Make sure our UI is in the correct state.
                showDetails(mCurCheckPosition2);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt("curChoice2", mCurCheckPosition2);
            outState.putInt("shownChoice2", mShownCheckPosition2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            showDetails(position);
        }

        /**
         * Helper function to show the details of a selected item, either by
         * displaying a fragment in-place in the current UI, or starting a
         * whole new activity in which it is displayed.
         */
        void showDetails(int index) {
            mCurCheckPosition2 = index;
            int upIndex0 = 0;
            int upIndex1 = 0;
            if (getArguments() != null)
            {
                upIndex0 = getArguments().getInt("index0", 0);
                upIndex1 = getArguments().getInt("index1", 0);
            }

            if (mDualPane2) {
                // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
                // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
                getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

            } else {
                // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
                // the dialog fragment with selected text.
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("index0", upIndex0);
                intent.putExtra("index1", upIndex1);
                intent.putExtra("index2", index);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here are the constants:

```
public final class Shakespeare {
    /**
     * Our data, part 1.
     */
    public static final String[] TITLES0 = 
    {
            "NFL",   
            "MLB"
    };

    public static final String[] TITLES00 = 
    {
            "NFC West",   
            "NFC East",
            "AFC West"
    };

    public static final String[] TITLES01 = 
    {
            "No Groups"
    };

    public static final String[] TITLES000 = 
    {
            "49ers",   
            "Seahawks",
            "Rams",       
            "Cardinals"
    };

    public static final String[] TITLES001 = 
    {
            "Cowboys",   
            "Giants",
            "Egales",       
            "Redskins"
    };

    public static final String[] TITLES002 = 
    {
            "Chargers",   
            "Chiefs",
            "Broncos",       
            "Raiders"
    };

    public static final String[] TITLES010 = 
    {
            "No members"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I shouldn't need to dynamically add those ListFragments because there are already specified in the XML file.  All I need to do is to find the ListFragment:

TitlesFragment2 tf2 = (TitlesFragment2)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.titles2);

and then update the list.